# Execute curl command in ansible

Tags: shell, curl, ansible, ambari

I am trying to pass this curl command in ansible playbook :

```
shell: 'curl -k -u {{ AMBARI_USER }}:{{ AMBARI_PASSWORD }} -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X POST -d '[{"Event": {"specs": [{"principal_type": "users", "sync_type": "all"}, {"principal_type": "groups", "sync_type": "all"}]}}]' https://{{AMBARI_SERVER_HOST}}:8083/api/v1/ldap_sync_events
```

here's my ansible playbook :

```
- hosts: adm
  tasks:
    - name: sync ldap
      shell: "curl -k -u {{ AMBARI_USER }}:{{ AMBARI_PASSWORD }} -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X POST -d '[{"Event": {"specs": [{"principal_type": "users", "sync_type": "all"}, {"principal_type": "groups", "sync_type": "all"}]}}]' https://{{AMBARI_SERVER_HOST}}:8083/api/v1/ldap_sync_events"
```

The thing is that this command has multiple double and simple cotes, so it's not wrking, is there anyway to pass it here or i should create a shell script for it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there a reason you're using plain shell commands instead of the [`uri`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html) module? A general best practice is to prefer Ansible modules. They already fit to Ansible (e.g. change detection, error handling), save you work and may care about security if needed.

For example, in your case it avoids struggeling with multiple nested quotes, since it abstracts the parameters instead of having a large call. Raw shell commands should only be used in  special cases, when the Ansible module doesn't work for the use case.

Something like this should fit for the base request using the `uri` module:

```
- name: Make an API call
  uri:
    method: POST
    url: "https://{{ AMBARI_SERVER_HOST }}:8083/api/v1/ldap_sync_events"
    url_username: "{{ AMBARI_USER }}"
    url_password: "{{ AMBARI_PASSWORD }}"
    body_format: json
    headers:
      'X-Requested-By': 'ambari'
```

Several ways exists to pass the JSON body:

- As string, which would be possible here since you don't need additional quotes as you needed for the `curl` call. 
  Something like this could be used:

  ```
  body: '[{"Event": ...'
  ```
- A Ansible data structure like an array. Ansible would automatically convert it to JSON, as long as `body_format` is set to the corresponding type as the case in my example above
- From a file. I'd prefer this if the JSON is larger, because you can directly paste the object there and have proper formatting, without messing the Ansible part. Just use `lookup` like this:

  ```
  body: "{{ lookup('file','api-body.json') }}"
  ```

Just add the desired `body` property to `uri`. For example, If you want to have a json file, like this:

```
- name: Make an API call
  uri:
    method: POST
    url: "https://{{ AMBARI_SERVER_HOST }}:8083/api/v1/ldap_sync_events"
    url_username: "{{ AMBARI_USER }}"
    url_password: "{{ AMBARI_PASSWORD }}"
    body: "{{ lookup('file','api-body.json') }}"
    body_format: json
    headers:
      'X-Requested-By': 'ambari'
    # If you're interested in the response
    return_content: yes
  register: api_result
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I will do this instead of the shell command.

Comment: This is good and it works for me. However, I have a problem giving parameters to json file. Variables as `ansible_default_ipv4.address` can be passed to that json file, but not `inventory_hostname` or `ansible_hostname`. Ansible version 2.9. I tried to define a variable within the playbook task, or in separate _vars/main.yml_ file.
Adding the json within the task/main.yml in a format: `body: '[{"Event": ...'` takes variables properly.